# update trigger issue

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

The trigger is giving me an error

> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY . Maximum trigger depth exceeded.

Now this trigger is working f9 in after insert event but i want it after update.
I can't understand where its going wrong.

```
trigger updatingsuffix on Account (after update) {
    List<Account> acclst=new List<Account>();
    Set<Id> accset=new Set<Id>();
    if(trigger.IsInsert){
        for(Account a:trigger.new){
            accset.add(a.Id);
        }

        for(Account a:[select Id,Name,Gender__c from Account where Id=:accset]){
            if(a.Gender__c=='Male'){
                a.Name='Mr. '+a.Name;
                acclst.add(a);
            }
            else if(a.Gender__c=='Female'){
                acclst.add(a);
            }
        }
        if(acclst!=null){
            update acclst;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for the response ,but the issue is same.

Comment: first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, updatingsuffix: maximum trigger depth exceeded is the exact error

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. An update trigger where all the logic is contained in a block dependent on the trigger being an insert trigger effectively does nothing.

Comment: @martin actually i rectified that but it worked using before update only. Neways thnx for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the advice offered in the `Apex Developer Guide` on [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm):

> There are two types of triggers:
>
> - *Before triggers* are used to update or validate record values before they’re saved to the database.
> - *After triggers* are used to access field values that are set by the system (such as a record's Id or LastModifiedDate field), and to affect changes in other records, such as logging into an audit table or firing asynchronous events with a queue. The records that fire the after trigger are read-only.

You are performing a field update, so use **`before`** events and set the fields in memory (on your trigger context records); your changes will commit to the database.

```
trigger Account on Account (before update)
{
    for (Account record : trigger.new)
    {
        if (record.Gender__c == 'Male')
        {
            record.Name = 'Mr. ' + record.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi adrian thnkx for the response , i know that it will work with insert. but kindly help me in updating the existing records and not on the insert. Means what changes i can do to update the existing records.

Comment: @vineet You need to use ***before*** events and remove your additional `update` call. You used `after update`. That's your problem.

Comment: ok i got the your point . actually now i am using before update event. its updating also but in a wrong way. like if the name earlier is Ms. vineet,itz updating it to Mr. Ms. vineet. So,could you please help me to remove Ms. after updation.

Comment: You need to add *conditions* to your logic. Right now you perform your field update unconditionally.

Comment: i think this will work upto some extent.  a.Name='Mr. '+a.Name.removeStart('Ms.');

Comment: @ adrian  thnks for clearing the issue.